# Odd repeating php fwrite in IE

Tags: php, fwrite

I've been having a really tough time fixing an error, where I submit an html form and take the information from that form and use it in a php script where I save it to a file.  In chrome and Firefox, it saves the data fine, no problems.  However, in IE, either the forms submits weird, or the php messes up, where it repeats saving the data 10 times.  So instead of "Test", I'm getting "TestTestTestTestTest..ect"

Does anybody know why this would occur in IE only?

The general code (not all included.. however, it's mostly just repeats of this):

```
<form id="form1" action="createProf.php" method="post">

<input type="radio" style="position:absolute; top: 218px; left: 560px;" id="female" name="gender" value="female"/>
<input type="radio" style="position:absolute; top: 187px; left: 560px;" id="male"   name="gender" value="male"/>
<input type="text" id="year" name="year" size="4" value="Year" style="position:absolute; top: 416px; left: 640px;"/>
</form>

    //php code//
$gender = htmlspecialchars($_POST['gender']);
$acc = fopen($file, 'r') or die("cant open file");
//other reading code and other stuff ehre
fwrite($acc, $data);
fclose($acc);
```

Thanks, and if more is needed to help, I'm willing to add more on.

Comment: how can you write to a file you only open for read ?

Comment: Good point.. I copied the wrong code, that was from 10 lines up from what I meant to post:

$acc = fopen($file, 'w') or die("cant open file");

fwrite($acc, $data);

Comment: How is $data populated?  seems like you left out important code.

Comment: $data is defined as "$data = substr($prev_data, 0, $endpos)" 

where $prev_data is the data from the previous file (hence the accidental 'r' above)

$endpos is a position..

when I do "<?php echo $data ?>" I get "Test" on the html screen, but I get TestTestTest..ect in my php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I said something wrong for people not to answer me and to -1 my post.

Anyways, I found an answer to my problem where I just check to see if the data from the last save is already there, which then I don't write and close the file.  I wish there was a cleaner way, but I guess for now this is what I have to use.

```
if(strpos(fread($acc, filesize($file)), "identification_string")==false){ 
//Write to file
}
```